# Silverstripe SQL Logic

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

I am trying to run a query but something strange happens:

```
$return = MyCustomPage::get()->where(
    " MyCustomPage.ID IN(" . implode(',', $MyCustomPageIds) . ")"
)->limit(2);
```

This return an error becasue the query it's trying to get data from **MyCustomPage_Live** instead of **MyCustomPage** .

This logic keeps like changing, sometimes it get from one table sometimes from another, and I need to specify the table name inside the query (ex. MyCustomPage.ID or MyCustomPage_Live.ID )

Is there a better way to to this or any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to avoid raw SQL queries as much as possible and leverage the [SilverStripe ORM](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/) instead.

So to achieve the same you did with your where statement, but by using the ORM you would write:

```
$return = MyCustomPage::get()->byIDs($MyCustomPageIds)->limit(2);
```

This will also automatically read from the current stage. If you need to force a stage to read from, you can use something like:

```
// replace 'Live' with 'Stage' to read from stage. 
Versioned::set_stage('Live');
```

In these cases it's also good practice to store the current stage first and restore it after.

```
$currentStage = Versioned::get_stage(); 
Versioned::set_stage('Live');

// Do your thing…

Versioned::set_stage($currentStage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `where` statement to do this, you could do something along the lines of `CustomPage::get()->filter(['ID' => $CustomPageArray])->limit(2)` instead. Arrays as a second argument in SilverStripe are treated as an `IN` type of query. Using a `filter` will also automatically solve the versioning problem which is what you run in to.

If you really need to use a `where`, something like this would help:

```
$extra = '';
if (Versioned::current_stage() == 'Live') {
     $extra = '_live'
}
Page::get()->where('MyFilter' . $extra . '.ID' IN implode(',', $CustomIds));
```

enter code here

(Excuse any syntax errors ;) )